# How to copy all the dependencies in Maven project modules to a directory?

Tags: maven, build, copy, maven-3, artifactory

I have a big local maven project that contains multiple modules which are inturn maven projects and are dependent on one another.

Ex.

**parent pom.xml**

```
<pom>
   <module1> #jar
   <module2> #dependent_on_module1.jar
   <module3> #
</pom>
```

I have mentioned the sequence to build those modules in the parent pom.xml .

I also mentioned where to place the artifacts when they're built in groudId and artifactId.

But in the dependencies for all those modules, I have mentioned a common local system path for all those modules.

Is there any way to copy all the artifacts which are being created for modules when  maven  build is performed on the parent pom to a specific directory that can be dynamically mentioned when the maven command is run.

I have searched for maven copy command. But looks like it's not going to do what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Mentioning the order in pom is not relevant. You have to define the correct dependencies between the modules and maven will order them accordingly. You can create a jar-with-dependencies which means containing all dependencies within a single jar (executable jar). Furthermore is this a command line application or something like JEE (WAR/EAR) or Spring Boot etc. ? Can you give more details and very helpful would also be having the pom files..

Comment: all the modules are jars which are used in another maven based struts project. Is there any command to copy the jars which are being created?

Comment: If you are using it by another Maven project just do `mvn install` or better using a repository manager via `mvn deploy` and on the other side just use as dependencies?

Comment: for now I just want all the artifacts from the project to be copied into a common local directory like a library or something which I can use to refer to as `systempath` in other local projects. Is there any way to achieve that?